# Automatic scrolling when element is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever an element is removed from DOM, all elements below it move up to take the newly freed position. Is there anyway to change it so that if an element is focussed which is below the removed element, all element above it will move down (i.e. scroll down) and focussed element's position will remain unchanged.

See this code

```
<div id="foo">
  <br><br>
</div>
<textarea id="bar" onkeypress="removeFoo()"></textarea>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/du1mjmz7/1/). Whenever you type a character in text area it abruptly moves to take up the free space obtained by removing the div. I want to prevent this behaviour as it looks odd.

Edit: Objective is to make the removing seamless. If this focussed element is last element in viewable area then it will definitely move up, however if it is in middle of screen then elements above it should move down so that focussed element is not moved.

Comment: Do you have to remove? could you not use the hide() function instead?

Comment: No I want to remove the element from the DOM.

Comment: So you want to remove element but still keep space in viewport this removed element was taking? It looks like weird behaviour imho

Comment: @A.Wolff I do not want to keep the space in viewport. I want the position of focussed element not change if possible.

Comment: I think this might can help you
    https://jsfiddle.net/du1mjmz7/4/

Comment: @hjardine's comment will work. try using `jquery.slideUp();`

Answer (score 0):

you must use CSS to scroll the `<divid="foo"></div>`

Like here see:

```
<style>
#foo{overflow-x:scroll;
OR
overflow-y:scroll;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about scrolling the window to the top of "focused element" after it moves up to take the free space?

```
function () {
      $("#id-of-elem-to-remove").slideUp();

      var focused = $("#id-of-focused-elem");
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: focused.offset().top
      }, 1000);
    });
```

**Edit**:

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnwz94xf/). Try removing "6" or "7".

Comment: This will also result in moving of element which I ultimately want to avoid.

Comment: so what exactly do you want? keep the focused element where it is and shift the next element on top of focused element? and btw, what do you mean by "focused" element?

Comment: I read your edit. Moving the top elements down will shift the empty space to the top of the document. what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get current scroll position and removable element's height, then, after removing the element, set the scroll position to the current scroll position minus element height:

```
function removeFoo() {
  var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var ele = document.getElementById("foo");
  var height = ele.offsetHeight;
  console.log(tempScrollTop, height);
  ele.parentElement.removeChild(ele);
  $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop - height);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/du1mjmz7/3/

P.S. I added jquery to make it faster for me, but you get the idea. Also your script doesn't work when it tries to remove element second time because element doesn't exist anymore (didn't try to fix it)